# Solve the differential equation $y''=-ky^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to figure out if the spring constant $k$ is inversely proportional to the period of oscillations of a spring in a quartic force law $F=cy^2$. Can anyone solve this differential equation?
$$y''=-ky^2$$

Thanks,

Lol_man000

Comment: Did you try to multiply by $y'$ ? $y′′=−ky^2  \implies 2y'y''=-k \frac 2 3 (y^3)'$

Comment: Put $y'=p$. Then $y''= p\frac{dp}{dy}$. The equation is now separable.

Comment: Your equation can be written in a conservation of energy format as: $\frac{dE}{dt}=0$ where $E=-k\frac{y^3}{3}+\frac{1}{2}(y’)^2$ is the sum of the springs potential and kinetic energies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply both sides by $y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$ to get $y'' y' = -ky^2 y'$. Now notice that $y'' y' = \frac{d}{dx} \big[\frac{1}{2}(y')^2\big]$ and $-ky^2y' =  \frac{d}{dx} \big[{-}\frac{k}{3}y^3\big]$ (by the Chain Rule). So we have
$$\frac{d}{dx} \bigg[\frac{1}{2}(y')^2\bigg] = \frac{d}{dx} \bigg[{-}\frac{k}{3}y^3\bigg].$$
Then integrating both sides with respect to $x$ and multiplying by $2$,
$$(y')^2 = -\frac{2}{3}ky^3 + C \implies y' =  \pm \sqrt{C-\frac{2}{3}ky^3},$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. Now we have reduced to a first-order ODE which we can solve by separation of variables.
\begin{align}
    \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{C-\frac{2}{3}ky^3}} &= \int \pm 1\, dx = \pm x + D \\[5pt]
\end{align}
where $D$ is an arbitrary constant. Unfortunately, the integral on the LHS is quite nasty and does not have a closed-form solution.

Comment: It's the derivative of $y^3$ on the rhs. That's why it's complicated to integrated once the order of the DE is reduced.

Comment: You solved $y''=-ky$ when Op's DE is $y''=-k\color{red}{y^2}$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Just corrected it.

Comment: No problem yw Leonidas

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to multiply by $2y'$ ? 
$$y′′=−ky^2  \implies 2y'y''=-k \frac 2 3 (y^3)'$$
$$ \implies (y'^2)'=-k \frac 2 3 (y^3)'$$
Integration will reduce the order of the DE. But it's not sure the first order DE will be easy to integrate

Answer (score 0):

This is not a spring, there is no restoring force for $y<0$. A valid quadratic law would be $y''=-ky|y|$. In all non-linear forces/non-quadratic potentials, the oscillation frequency also depends on the amplitude of the oscillation.

However, the original question can be answered directly by changing the time scale. Setting $u(s)=y(s/\sqrt{k})$ in $y''=-k\phi(y)$, one gets
$$
u''(s)=y''(s/\sqrt{k})/k=-\phi(y(s/\sqrt{k}))=-\phi(u(s)).
$$
Thus in the rescaled time the motion is independent of $k$.
This means for the original problem that under a change of $k$ the oscillation frequency (if there is an oscillation) changes with its square root, the period inverse to it.